# Use variables per branch in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have set up my GitLab pipeline and I'm using GitLab CI variables to generate my configuration file during the build phase. Now we've set up a couple new environments, with each having its own database and other credentials, so I need to generate my configuration file using each environment's variables based on branch. I've already seen:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14223

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/13379

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/8858

https://medium.com/spacepilots/sourcing-environment-variables-in-gitlab-ci-or-a-poor-mans-dotenv-dfc33ca231df

Some users suggested sourcing environment variables from files but that isn't really a solution because we want to limit access to these variables.
Is there a solution or workaround to this problem in *.gitlab-ci.yaml*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The following example will echo `${TEST_VAR}` depending on the branch (dev or main).

```
.test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "${TEST_VAR}"

test-dev-job:
  variables:
    TEST_VAR: "dev-value"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
  extends: .test-job

test-main-job:
  variables:
    TEST_VAR: "main-value"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
  extends: .test-job
```